# Callback function from dll pass garbage string?

Tags: delphi-2010

I am working with EPSON Advanced Printer Driver, when I open status API I pass the printer name as parameter to DLL,when i read the Checks it return result as call back procedure(GetMicrDataEx) with Printer name which I pass to BiOpenMonPrinter.
every thing working fine ,except Printer name at callback function is like garbage data.

BiOpenMonPrinter: Function( nType : LongInt; pName : PAnsiChar) : LongInt; cdecl;
       // pName :specify the printer name (example: "EPSON TM-H6000II Receipt").

```
    @BiMICRSetReadBackEx:= getprocaddress(libraryhnd,PAnsiChar('BiMICRSetReadBackFunctionEx'));

//BiMICRSetReadBackEx Lib 'EpsStmApi.Dll" 
BiMICRSetReadBackEx:Function( nHandle : LongInt;{int} CallBack:TProcedurePortName; {int}
             Var readBuffSize : Integer; {LPBYTE} readCharBuff : Pointer; {LPBYTE}
             pStatus : Pointer; pDetail : Pointer): LongInt; Stdcall;
```

I pass GetMicrDataEx as callback procedure.
the problem is when i receive callback ,printer name is long string with garbage charter

```
Procedure GetMicrDataEx(sPrintername:PAnsiChar); 
begin
//I receive garbage for printer name
end;
```

BiOpenMonPrinter:

> Makes Status API available for the printer and returns the handle.

BiMICRSetReadBackFunctionEx:

> Executes reading of checks by BiMICRReadCheck and registers the
>   address of the callback function when the results are notified as well
>   as the memory addresses where each type of information read from the
>   check is set.

i would appreciate your help
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very likely this is down to mismatching calling conventions. Your `GetMicrDataEx` callback uses the `register` calling convention. Likely the DLL expects a function that uses `stdcall`. Make `GetMicrDataEx` use `stdcall` to solve the problem.

Note that I have had to make a lot of guesses to write this answer because the question includes only one side of the interop interface. For such questions you really do need to include both sides of the interop interface.

Comment: Thank you David  ,It fixed i added stdcall  to my callback procedure .Thanks for your help it was really useful and fixed my issue .